# Is any group homomorphism $f:\Bbb Z\times\Bbb Z\to\Bbb Z\times\Bbb Z$ of the form $\phi_*:\pi_1(T_2) \to \pi_1(T_2)$ for some map $\phi: T_2 \to T_2$?

Tags: algebraic-topology

Let $T_2=S^1\times S^1$. I know that $\pi_1(T_2)\cong\Bbb Z\times\Bbb Z$.

Is any group homomorphism $f:\Bbb Z\times\Bbb Z\to\Bbb Z\times\Bbb Z$ of the form $\phi_*:\pi_1(T_2) \to \pi_1(T_2)$ for some continuous map $\phi: T_2 \to T_2$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Group homomorphisms $\Bbb Z\times\Bbb Z\to\Bbb Z\times\Bbb Z$ correspond to a matrix $\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{pmatrix}$ where $(m,n)\mapsto(ma+nb,mc+nd)$ under the homomorphism.

So for any such matrix, can we find a suitable $\phi$? Yes. Let $(z_1,z_2)\mapsto(z_1^az_2^b,z_1^cz_2^d)$. This is continuous, and under the canonical identifications $(S_1,1)\cong\Bbb Z$, $\pi_1(X\times Y)\cong\pi_1(X)\times\pi_1(Y)$, $\phi_\ast$ will have the desired matrix.